# strange shortcode error: does shortcodes requires any dependency?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, shortcode, widgets

Are there any dependencies on which shortcode depends?

`[news_weber][/news_weber]` → Didn't work, but when used with `do_shortcode` method it worked.

I installed [Ultimate shortcode plugin](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/shortcodes-ultimate.latest-stable.zip) to check whether that works or not. all the shortcodes of that plugin worked, strangely as soon as that plugin was installed my custom shortcodes also worked and as soon as uninstalled my custom shortcodes stopped working. what is the connection?

are there any dependencies that are not included in my theme and they get included as soon as some third-party plugin is installed?

## Update →

1. The shortcode works if used in the `post(edit mode) editor`, and
2. It also works with `do_shortcode` method, but
3. It doesn't work when we use the default text widget and place our
   shortcode there. However, it works here also If we install the plugin as I told you above.

[image]

**what is the issue?**

## Update 2: Code →

```
function burner() {
        ob_start();
        $random=rand(1,10000);
        ?>
        //some code
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('news_burner', 'burner');
```

## Update #3

Shortcodes are plugin territory so I transferred them to a plugin, but the same problem they do not work, but when I install a 3rd party plugin as stated above they do work.

Comment: Where's the `news_weber` shortcode coming from? There's no code in your question to debug

Comment: Sir, i have updated the question.

Comment: I have updated the code of one shortcode.

Comment: `news_weber` shortcode is in shortcode.php and that file is included in functions.php Additionally, the shortcode works in the post editors.

Comment: Have you tried just using `[news_weber]`? Without the closing shortcode?

Comment: Yes sir, I did, in that case, it doesn't work even if that 3rd party plugin is installed. Is it related to something apply_filters? But the shortcode `[news_burner]` works well in the post editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1

It doesn't work because you're using `new_weber` but you're registering `news_burner`, and they aren't the same

So instead use:

`[news_burner]`

You only need a closing shortcode if it's containing content which that plugin does not.

### Problem 2

Shortcodes don't work in text widgets out of the box, you can add that functionality via a plugin though, see this question/answer:

[Shortcode in Text Widget not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156222/shortcode-in-text-widget-not-working/156229)

This is why it works with `do_shortcode` but not in widgets. It'll also work in post content

Comment: [new_weber ] for Aweber; [news_burner] for Feedburner. I have total 4: aweber, mailchimp, Feedburner, feedblitz

Comment: Great, see the problem 2 section

Comment: sir, I didnt get this completely → "you can add that functionality via a plugin though" means my own custom text widget?

Comment: sir mystery solved → `add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode', 11 );` I added this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and my understanding of your question, you have to make sure that your shortcode is called from your functions files.

First, you need to write `<?php echo do_shortcode("[news_weber]"); ?>` in order to make it work by PHP. Based on your question, I think you do not need the closing bracket since shortcodes can be self-closed.

Documentation : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

But even if you typed this correctly, you still need to give the access to this shortcode in your function file.

You could create a custom file named `shortcodes.php` and call it from your `functions.php` file.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'my_theme_setup' ) ) :

   function my_theme_setup() {

   // Custom shortcodes
   require_once( "inc/shortcodes.php" );
}

endif;

add_action( "after_setup_theme", "my_theme_setup" );
```

And in your `shortcode.php` file you can call your function.

```
function news_weber_func( $atts ) {
    // Your custom code
}
add_shortcode( 'news_weber', 'news_weber_func' );
```

Official documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

I hope it will help you.

Comment: sir, I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: If I use shortcode w/o closing bracket then even after that plugin is installed it doesn't work.